# vector OF raster

Tags: r, vector, raster

i am trying to create a vector of raster in R, let me explain.
I'm working on data (24 month, jan,jan2,etc, and for different years), and, for each month (jan,jan2,feb,feb2,etc) i want to create a raster.

I did it by hand, but it's really long and i am trying to optimize a bit this code. I'm using a function, and a loop inside this function to create my raster. But as you imagine, it doesn't work. I wanted to automate the creation of my raster by month.

I did that for now (here i just tried for 5 .tif files):

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(stringr)
setwd(dir = "E:/perso/NEON-DS-Field-Site-Spatial-Data/SJER")
files_vec=list.files(path = "E:/perso/NEON-DS-Field-Site-Spatial-Data/SJER",full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)
files_vec

month<-c("jan","jan2","fev","fev2","mar")

vec_of_raster<-c("raster",length(files_vec))

raster_vec<-function(vec_of_raster,files_vec,month,year_str)
{
  for (i in seq(1,length(files_vec)))
  {
     vec_of_raster[i]<-(month[i]<-raster(files_vec[i]))
  }
}

raster_vec(vec_of_raster,files_vec,month,"1995")
```

I'm afraid i want to use two objects (raster and vector) that are either to close to work that way, or can't be associate.

Here are the errors (and warnings) that i get :

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In month[i] <- raster(files_vec[i]) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In vec_of_raster[i] <- (month[i] <- raster(files_vec[i])) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In month[i] <- raster(files_vec[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In vec_of_raster[i] <- (month[i] <- raster(files_vec[i])) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In month[i] <- raster(files_vec[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
6: In vec_of_raster[i] <- (month[i] <- raster(files_vec[i])) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
7: In month[i] <- raster(files_vec[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
8: In vec_of_raster[i] <- (month[i] <- raster(files_vec[i])) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
9: In month[i] <- raster(files_vec[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
10: In vec_of_raster[i] <- (month[i] <- raster(files_vec[i])) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length


Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

I don't get those error messages, if you can help me, or you had the same or a similar problem, i'm taking any hint !

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you should probably use double brackets `[[ ]]`

But you would use either `stack` (if the rasters *can* be stacked --- they need to have the same extent and resolution), or else `lapply`. Deal with the names after that, if necessary.

```
library(raster)

# example file for reproducibility
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
ff <- rep(f, 3)

s <- stack(ff)
s
#class       : RasterStack 
#dimensions  : 115, 80, 9200, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
#extent      : 178400, 181600, 329400, 334000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +init=epsg:28992 +towgs84=565.237,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857,0.350733,-1.87035,4.0812 +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs 
#names       :  test.1,  test.2,  test.3 
#min values  : 128.434, 128.434, 128.434 
#max values  : 1805.78, 1805.78, 1805.78
```

If you really want have a list (or cannot make a RasterStack)

```
x <- lapply(ff, raster)
names(x) <- basename(extension(ff, ""))
```

Comment: So, if i understand you, you're telling me that i should stack all my files and after creating a raster with my stack ? (sorry but i don't get what f is, system.file give you the full name of a file in a package, but i don't get why we should use it, i understand that after you'r just reproducing the same file just for the test, but not the system.file, could you explain to me ?)                                                     I don't absolutely need a list, i just want to get things done with this code ^^ in a more compact way if possible, so anything that can work !

Comment: questions and answers should be reproducible; that is why I use an file that comes with R. In your case you can use `list.files`. If you have trouble at this level, I suggest that you study R (and R spatial) a bit more. This might help: http://www.rspatial.org/